# Must velocity be constant velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, velocity

In terms of Momentum, in many highschool and even first year problems, it seems that the velocities used are all Constant velocity in terms of conservation of momentum.
But if the objects are accelerating, that is the velocities are changing at each moment in time, does conservation of momentum hold?
Also,
In term of Impulse being $\rightarrow$ $I = Fdt = \Delta p=M_2V_2 - M_1V_1$,
This is usually a non-zero value, and it seems to say that the object has changing velocity, hence acceleration.

SO would having impulse I = 0 mean that momentum is conserved while if impulse is not zero that it is not conserved?

So trying to understand Momentum properly in terms of what kind of velocity we are talking about.

Hope someone will clarify here.

Comment: Momentum exists at each instant in time. Conservation of momentum is a process which spans more than one time frame.

Comment: I will really like to help you but may you please give me an example of what it is that you're not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "So trying to understand Momentum properly in terms of what kind of velocity we are talking about."

There is only one *kind* of velocity. It is the instantaneous rate of change of some distance measurement.

- In each time frame, every particle in a system has defined properties of position and velocity. This described the kinematics of the system.
- A particle of mass $m$ and velocity $v$ has momentum $p = m v$.
- This momentum may or may not change with time depending on the dynamics of the system.
- Forces are responsible for changing momentum.

So yes, an accelerating particles *has* momentum defined at every instant as $p=m v$, even when $v$ changes.

The fact that momentum changes over time (due to acceleration) requires there are forces in the system that do so.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the velocity can vary. This is the power of the principle. In Newtonian mechanics the idea is that if there is a cloud of particles all with forces between them and so all accelerating, nevertheless the *total* momentum of the cloud is unchanged (assuming no external forces).

One way to think of a force is that it is the transfer of momentum between two particles. So, momentum is conserved, but one particle transfers momentum to the other particle, causeing them both to change velocity. And we call that a force.

In this sense - force is the rate of change of momentum by definition, and the dynamics of the mechanical situation is covered by the theory of what causes the momentum to be transfered and at what rate.

Comment: If particles in a system are accelerating then how can there be no external forces?

Comment: Hi BobD, i am with you. Ponder Stibbons answer seems to miss this kind of detail.

Comment: Because there are forces between the particles. Consider two planets in an otherwise empty universe - the planets attract each other, so there is a force between. But there is no net force on the two planets. Newtons - equal and opposite forces dictum. An external force would mean the sum of the forces on the planets was non zero. And that would mean that momentum is not conserved. Unless you include the momentum flux into the system - in which case the system is not closed.

Comment: But in senior highschool courses in physics and first year university physics problems always seem to put the objects on frictionless surfaces hence the objects are traveling at constant velocity and when a collision (elastic) with another object, things change but right after the interaction they are back to moving at constant velocity. SO it is from this highschool training that makes me question what is going on here.

Comment: In a typical high school problem with two particles that collide and separate, the details of the forces during the collision are ignored, and the velocities are constant before and after the collision. But, in the more general case, for example, the force between the two particles might be the inverse square of the distance between them. Then the paths of the particles are not straight lines - but the total momentum is still conserved.

Comment: I should add - having a fixed table with friction would be an external force. Alternatively, one could say that the momentum flowing into the table is being ignored, and so the momentum of the objects is not conserved.

Answer (score 1):

If the objects are accelerating they must have an external force acting on them and hence an impulse $I_{\rm external}$ acts for a time $\Delta t$.

At the same time there are internal force acting on the bodies as a result of the collision.  These result in an impulse $I_{\rm collision}$ acts for the same time $\Delta t$.

Now it becomes a matter of comparing the magnitudes of the impulses as to whether the impulse due to the external force has a significant effect which in turn means that the magnitudes of the external force and the forces due to the collision have to be compared.

In the sort of problem that you meet in a basic mechanics course, eg two projectiles colliding in mid air or a projectile exploding, where the external force is the gravitational attraction of the Earth it is assumed that the impulse due to the external force is very small compared with that which occurs as a result of the collision.

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to say that i like all the answers provided by everyone here, Ponder Stibbons answers were great he drilled down a lot, I like the answer by Farcher by talking about external forces and Impulse. But ja72 got to the main issue i was having by saying: "There is only one kind of velocity. It is the instantaneous rate of change of some distance measurement. ". I wish i could choose all of the responses at the answer to this question.